# Estimating the XIRR of a very non uniform cash flows

Tags: returns, finance-mathematics, mathematics

It's my second post, so please bear my lack of experience in this field.

I've a very irregular cash flow (here you can see the set of date - cumulative cash flow)

The XIRR, calculated with Excel, is about 90%, so it seems a very good investment, but in the last year it got really worst (see the second graph). How can I calculate the IRR of an investment which behaves like the second graph?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There appears to be some kind of seasonal component to your cash flows.  Can you deseasonalize your CF and use that time-series to do the valuation

Comment: @Chris: thanks for the hint. The income payment always happen in the last week of each month, but the change in trend are not seasonal, they relate to an algorithmic change of Google (the income are related to the visibility on Google). Should I use timeseries the same?